# Is there a way to redirect to a specific page after a RESTful delete in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Lets say I have a message resource. Somewhere in the html I have:

```
<%= link_to("Delete", message, :title => 'Delete', :confirm => 'Are you sure?', 
   :method => :delete )%>
```

Right after I delete it, it redirects me to the page where it lists all the messages. Is there a way to redirect to a page that I specify after the deletion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the controller:

```
def delete
  Item.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to :action => "index"
end
```

To redirect to the last url, use:

```
redirect_to :back
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000662

If you can learn how to read api docs well, they are extremely useful, once you get the hang of them.

Comment: Specifically, change line 3 to point to where you want it to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the `destroy` action that you should be dealing with if you're using Rails' resources.

```
def destroy
  Item.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to other_specified_path
end
```

If you look at the API documentation, you'll see there's a HUGE difference between the `ActiveRecord::Base#delete` and `ActiveRecord::Base#destroy` methods.  Only use delete if you really understand why you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

i only need this

```
def delete
  Item.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end
```

i used this if i want to back to current page